# I'm stuck on a proof involving the of Axiom for multiplicative inverses and modular arithmetic.

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, axioms

I am trying to show that the axiom of multiplicative inverses holds on sets of integers modulo P when P is prime.

i just need to show that for any non zero integer, n less than P there is a unique multiple of n such that $nm \mod P = 1$.

i have proven the case that when $n = (p-1)$, m must also be (p-1).
since if '$ nm \mod P = 1$', $ nm = px + 1$ (where px is a multiple of p) and $(p-1)^2 = p^2 -2p + 1 = p(p-2) + 1$.

but this only holds for the (p-1) integer and doesn't prove the axiom holds.

I cant figure out how to show that every integer n less than P (not=0) has an m such that nm mod p = 1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: show that given any $a: 0 < a < p$ then $an$ is unique for each  $0 < n < p$. If $an$ is **not** unique then there exists an $m$ where $0 < m < p$, $m \ne n$ such that $am = an$.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to use Bezout's identity (if you haven't learnt that yet, look it up).